# Aggregation per Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have thousands of companies listed but for illustration; I cited 2 companies. I need to produce the column TotalSales in which values are the sum of sales per company , a year prior to its corresponding actual year & quarter.

```
Company         Sales   Quarter    Year      TotalSales    QtrYr_Included
ABC Inc.        10,000     1       2010         null       Q12009 - Q42009
ABC Inc.        50,000     2       2010        10,000      Q22009 - Q12010
ABC Inc.        35,000     3       2010        60,000      Q32009 - Q22010 
ABC Inc.        15,000     4       2010        95,000      Q42009 - Q32010
ABC Inc.         5,000     1       2011        110,000     Q12010 - Q42010
ABC Inc.        10,000     2       2011        105,000     Q22010 - Q12011
SoKor Group     50,000     1       2009         null       Q12008 - Q42008
SoKor Group     10,000     2       2009        50,000      Q22008 - Q12009
SoKor Group     10,000     3       2009        60,000      Q32008 - Q22009
SoKor Group      5,000     4       2009        70,000      Q42008 - Q32009
SoKor Group     15,000     1       2010          .         Q12009 - Q42009
SoKor Group     20,000     3       2010          .         Q22009 - Q12010
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: will the table *always* have data for all the quarters for a company?

Comment: so..in that case do you have to treat the missing quarter data as 0 and report the sum or consider quarters from a different year in a specified order?

Comment: @mnms2 - which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: @mnms2 - Run `select @@VERSION` and tell me the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `Sum Over` window aggregate

```
SELECT *,
       Sum(sales)
         OVER(
           partition BY Company
           ORDER BY [Year], [Quarter] ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
FROM   Yourtable
```

for Older versions

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY Company ORDER BY [Year], [Quarter]) rn,*
         FROM   Yourtable a)
SELECT *
FROM   cte a
       CROSS apply (SELECT Sum (sales) Total_sales
                    FROM   (SELECT TOP 4 sales
                            FROM   cte b
                            WHERE  a.Company = b.Company
                                   AND b.rn < a.rn
                            ORDER  BY [Year] DESC,
                                      [Quarter] DESC)a) cs
```

Comment: Prdp .. this assumes there is no missing data for any of the quarters. You should also show what happens when there is missing data and explain the alternate approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

@Prdp's solution is valid. However, it would show incorrect results when there are quarters missing for a given company as it will consider whatever row was available before the missing row. A way to avoid such situation is using derived tables to generate all combinations of year,quarter and company. Left joining the original table on to this result would generate 0 sales for the missing quarters. Then use the `sum` window function to get the sum of sales for the last 4 quarters for each row.

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (SELECT C.COMPANY,
         Y.[YEAR],
         Q.[QUARTER],
         T.SALES,
         SUM(COALESCE(T.SALES,0)) OVER(PARTITION BY C.COMPANY
                                       ORDER BY Y.[YEAR], Q.[QUARTER] 
                                       ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS PREV_4QTRS_TOTAL
  FROM
   (SELECT 2008 AS [YEAR]
    UNION ALL SELECT 2009
    UNION ALL SELECT 2010
    UNION ALL SELECT 2011
    UNION ALL SELECT 2012
    UNION ALL SELECT 2013) Y --Add more years as required or generate them using a recursive cte or a tally table
  CROSS JOIN
   (SELECT 1 AS [QUARTER]
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 4) Q
  CROSS JOIN
   (SELECT DISTINCT COMPANY
    FROM T) C
  LEFT JOIN T ON Y.[YEAR]=T.[YEAR]
  AND Q.[QUARTER]=T.[QUARTER]
  AND C.COMPANY=T.COMPANY 
) X
WHERE SALES IS NOT NULL --to filter the result to include only rows from the original table
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/MBJK53168)